# Boundary point sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^p$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$. Then $x$ is a
>   boundary point of $A$ if and only if there is a sequence $(a_n)$ of
>   elements in $A$ and a sequence $(b_n)$ of elements in $ \cal{C} (A)$ (where $\cal{C} (A)$ is the complement of $A$) such that $$lim(a_n)=x=lim(b_n)$$

Let $x$ be a boundary point of $A$, then $x$ is not an interior point to $A$. Since $x$ is a boundary point, does it necessary mean that it intersects $ \cal{C} (A)$? If not, how can I continue proceeding proving this?

Comment: What is $C(A)$? What do you mean by "let $C(A)$ be open"?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE It is the complement of $A$. I am going to edit.

Comment: You have assumed that $x \in C(A)$, so of course $x$ intersects $C(A)$.  Something is wrong here..

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Opps, I meant to take that off or it wouldnt make sense. That was a my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boundary point is either in $A$ or not. (For example, the boundary of $(-\infty, 0)$ is $\{0\}$, the boundary of $(-\infty, 0]$ is also $\{0\}$.)

The key point is that if $x$ is in the boundary of $A$, then any **open** set containing $x$ must intersect both $A$ **and** $A^c$.

To wit, suppose $x \in \partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$. Let $x \in U$, where $U$ is open. Then $U$ must intersect $A$ and $A^c$. To see the latter, suppose $U$ does not intersect $A$, then $A \subset \overline{A} \subset U^c$ (since $U^c$ is closed), which contradicts $x \in U$. A similar argument applies to $A^c$.

Now choose $U_n = B(x,\frac{1}{n})$, and pick $a_n \in U_n \cap A$, $b_n \in U_n \cap A^c$. Clearly $a_n \in A$, and $a_n \to x$. Similarly $b_n \in A^c$ and $b_n \to x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, copper! Is $U_n = B(x,\frac{1}{n})$ an open ball and why did you choose $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, it is an open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\frac{1}{n}$. There is nothing special about $\frac{1}{n}$, any positive sequence that converges to zero will do.

Comment: Understand, thanks a lot!

Comment: Copper, I have a couple of questions. What is $\bar A$? Is it just $A$ and why does $U^c$ being closed contradict that $x\in U$? And in the last sentence why is it clear that $a_n \to x$, I see why $a_n\in A$ but cant see why it goes to $x$?

Comment: $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$, and it is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$. Since $U^c$ is closed, and contains $A$, it must therefore contain $\overline{A}$, and hence we must have $x \in U^c$, which contradicts $x \in U$. Since $a_n \in U_n$, we have $|a_n - x| < \frac{1}{n}$. This is why $a_n \to x$.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clearing that up!